# Unable to locate website API for web-scraping - no json response found

Tags: json, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape council tax band data from this website and I'm unable to find the API:

https://ecitizen.aberdeencity.gov.uk/publicaccesslive/selfservice/services/counciltax/bandsearchresults.htm?action=pageNavigation&p=0

I've gone through previous answers on Stack Overflow and articles including:

```
http://www.gregreda.com/2015/02/15/web-scraping-finding-the-api/
```

and

```
https://medium.com/@williamyeny/finding-ratemyprofessors-private-api-with-chrome-developer-tools-bd6747dd228d
```

I've gone into the Network tab - XHR/All - Headers/ Preview/ Response and the only thing I can find is:

```
/**/jQuery11130005376436794664263_1594893863666({ "html" : "<li class='navbar-text myprofile_salutation'>Welcome Guest!</li><li role='presentation' class=''><a href='https://ecitizen.aberdeencity.gov.uk/publicaccesslive/selfservice/citizenportal/login.htm?redirect_url=https://ecitizen.aberdeencity.gov.uk/publicaccesslive/selfservice/dashboard.htm'> Sign In / Register <span class='icon-arrow-right17 pull-right visible-xs-block'></span></a></li>" });
```

As a test I used **AB24 4DE** to search and couldn't find it anywhere within a json response.

As far as I can tell the data isn't hidden behind a web socket.

I ran a get request for the sake of it and got:

```
JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 10 column 1 (char 19)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing the right thing looking at the network tools. I find it's best to zoom in on the overview you're given in the network tab. You can select any proportion of an action in the browser. See what is happening which requests are made. So you could focus on the start of requests and responses when you click search. It gives you two requests that are made, one to post information to the server and one grabs information to a seperate url.

### Suggestion

My suggestion having had a look at the website is to probably use selenium which is a package that mimics browser activity. Below you'll see my study of the requests. Essentially the form generates a unique token for every time you do a search. YOu have to replicate inorder to get the correct response. Which is hard to know in advance.

That being said, you can mimic browser activity using selenium and automatically input the postcode and automating the clicking of the search button. You then can grab the page source HTML and use beautifulsoup to parse it. Here is a minimal reproducible example showing you this.

### Coding Example

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'c:\users\aaron\chromedriver.exe')
url = 'https://ecitizen.aberdeencity.gov.uk/publicaccesslive/selfservice/services/counciltax/bandsearch.htm'                          
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('postcode').send_keys('AB24 4DE')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@class="btn btn-primary cap-submit-inline"]').click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
```

There is also scope to make the browser headless, so it doesn't popup and all you'll get back is the parsed html.

### Explanation of Code

We are importing webdriver from selenium, this provides the module necessary to load a browser. We then create an instance of that webdriver, in this case I'm using chrome but you can use firefox or other browsers.

You'll need to download chromedriver from here, https://chromedriver.chromium.org/. Webdriver uses this to open a browser.

We use the get webdriver get method to make chromedriver go to the specific page we want.

Webdriver has a list of find element by... you can use. The simplest here is `find_element_by_id`. We can find the id of the input box in the HTML for inputting the postcode, which I've done here. Send_keys will send whatever text we want, in this case its AB24 4DE.

find_element_by_xpath takes an XPATH selector. '//' goes through all of the DOM, we select input and the [@class=""] part selects the specifc input tag class. We want the submit button. The click() method, will click that browser.

We then grab the page source once this click is complete, this is necessary as we then input that into BeuatifulSoup, which will give us the parsed HTML of the postcode we desire.

### Reverse Engineering the HTTP requests

Below is for education really, unless someone can get the unique token before sending requests to the server. Here's how the website works in terms of the search form.

Essentially looking at the process, it's sending cookies,headers,params and data to a server. The cookies has a session ID which does't seem to change on my test. The data variable is where you can change the postcode but also importantly the ABCtoken changes for every single time you want to do a search and the param is a check on the server to make sure it's not a bot.

As an in example of the HTTP POST request here. We send this

```
cookies = {
    'JSESSIONID': '1DBAC40138879EB418C14AD83C05AD86',
}

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Origin': 'https://ecitizen.aberdeencity.gov.uk',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Referer': 'https://ecitizen.aberdeencity.gov.uk/publicaccesslive/selfservice/services/counciltax/bandsearch.htm',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

params = (
            ('action', 'validateData'),
         )

data = {
  'postcode': 'AB24 2RX',
  'address': '',
  'startSearch': 'Search',
  'ABCToken': '35fbfd26-cb4b-4688-ac01-1e35bcb8f63d'
}
```

To

`https://ecitizen.aberdeencity.gov.uk/publicaccesslive/selfservice/services/counciltax/bandsearch.htm`

Then it's doing an HTTP GET request here with the same JSESSIONID and the unique ABCtoken to grab the data you want to bandsearchresults.html

```
'https://ecitizen.aberdeencity.gov.uk/publicaccesslive/selfservice/services/counciltax/bandsearchresults.htm'
```

So it's creating a JSESSIONID which seems to be the same for any postcode from my testing. then when you use that same JSESSIONID and you use the ABCtoken it supplies  the searchresults URL you'll get the correct data back.

Comment: thank you for the explanations, very useful especially since web-scraping not my strong point. I have tried to use selenium previously but, because I'm working out of IBM Watson and Python is installed via conda, I haven't been able to figure out yet how to effectively install the Chrome webdriver in it. There is already an open question on it in Stack Overflow with no replies. If by any chance you've come across the answer I'd appreciate it. If not, I'll mark your answer as accepted and come back to it once I've figured out the above. Thanks!

Comment: if you can install the selenium package and point towards a directory with chromedriver.exe in it. you should be able to run it with selenium. Are you able to build the conda package ? (https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/building-conda-packages.html). Do you have other packages installed? If so how were they installed ?

Comment: I'd also be interested in hearing whether someone is able to get the ABCtoken which appears with every form post, prior to doing it. It can't see a way using requests/beautifulsoup etc.. You can as I have said in the answer once you have that ABCtoken grab the data using requests and beautifulsoup but that's the stumbling block. You seem to need to simulate browser activity to get that.

Comment: Having thought on this awhile, it might be worth checking out selenium-wire. It's an add on to selenium where you can grab detail on the requests made of the browser. So you could simulate a search procedure, grab the ABC token and then grab the data in a highly structured manner. It would have to be hard coded into each time you want to do a search per postcode but it's a viable option.